# how to add magento widgets in static block

Tags: magento

i created a magento widgets and its working fine with the cms pages , now i want to use this widgets in to static block . how can do this

Comment: Why don't you  use `CMS -> Widgets` functionality? By the way, CMS Block it is a sort of widget.

Comment: @webkul please help me here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101629/skip-custom-shipping-method-in-checkout

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92656/quantity-is-not-saving-in-database

Answer (score 4):

On the WYSIWYG editor, there is a button for Widgets and you can select which widget you want to include in your CMS block...

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer is the most elusive one :)

The button is second from the upper left on my install, it looks like a tiny Magento logo with a crosshair over it.